# C++ memory management questions (allocate lots of memories but never free them)

Tags: c++, memory

In C++, I intent to allocate memories using 'new' and allocate lots of memories until the memories reach the maximum of the computer. What will happen if I never use 'delete' to free memory? Thanks.

Comment: You will run out of memory. What else do you expect?

Comment: All memory will be reclaimed by the operating system when your program terminates, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: The program will crash

Comment: I've faced two possible variants: 1) the program being killed by the OS (Ubuntu, Fedora Linux). 2) the OS hang (Red Hat 5, sometimes other OS's)

Comment: [This is what happens](http://ideone.com/2jraal). If it's not obvious, a `std::bad_alloc` exception is C++'s way of saying "You ran out of memory".

Comment: @lxrec under many OS's that isn't what happens, due to optimistic virtual memory allocation.  Instead, the call to the new operator succeeds, but then when the program actually tries to access the memory at the returned address, the program will crash because the OS cannot provide the physical memory to go with the virtual addresses that were allocated.

Answer (score 3):

Your computer will run out of memories.

Comment: Que the Daft Punk...